# How to Configure ADFS authentication for .Net Core using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, adfs

Please let me know, if there are any example which demonstrate its implementation or relative links.

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend you [this](https://gavindraper.com/2013/01/31/ad-fs-token-based-authentication-in-code/) tutorial because:

- It is really simple (step by step)
- It shows you how to proceed on visual studio and on iis
- It shows sample code